# python calculate average of previous rows for a certain company

Tags: python, average, rolling-computation

I would like to calculate the 2-day average prc of a certain ticker in the data shown in the image below.
I am aware of `df.PRC.rolling(window=2).mean()`, however, this would not give me the desired results.

Thanks a lot for helping out!

Data:

[image: data]

Comment: So what are the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies. This solves the problem.

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('TICKER').rolling(2)['PRC'].mean().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Regards, Darcy